# Iterate through n children in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, directory, subdirectory, bookmarks

I'm trying to iterate through every bookmark in a bookmark folder.

```py
for parent_folder in json_object['roots']['bookmark_bar']['children']:
       if path == desired_path:
              return parent_folder

       for child1 in parent_folder['children']:
              if path == desired_path:
                     return child1 

              for child2 in child1['children']:
                     if path == desired_path:
                            return child2
```

Is there a better way to do this so that I can iterate through `n` children? Right now I have to create a `for` loop for each subdirectory with a new `child` variable.

Forgive me, I can't think of a better way to ask the question but hopefully you get the jist of what I'm trying to get at.

Sample `json_object` input:

```json
{
   "checksum": "6b65109d4aedcafd5afdbf60c2c550c6",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "children": [ {
               "children": [ {
                  "children": [ {
                     "children": [ {
                        "date_added": "13264531526257514",
                        "date_last_used": "13312079908225289",
                        "guid": "28a9a0b5-9358-435c-a961-183877d528c5",
                        "id": "9",
                        "name": "Log In to My Account | American Express US",
                        "show_icon": false,
                        "source": "unknown",
                        "type": "url",
                        "url": "https://www.americanexpress.com/en-us/account/login"
                     }, {
                        "date_added": "13264624495902630",
                        "date_last_used": "13311480110897463",
                        "guid": "eb271305-3da6-47b0-9b29-0b188a49de4c",
                        "id": "10",
                        "name": "Discover Card: Session Ended",
                        "show_icon": false,
                        "source": "unknown",
                        "type": "url",
                        "url": "https://portal.discover.com/customersvcs/universalLogin/timeout_confirmed"
                     } ],
                     "date_added": "13312413888903462",
                     "date_last_used": "0",
                     "date_modified": "13312413894732480",
                     "guid": "45822356-c1a0-4644-a36b-d1805994bff1",
                     "id": "23",
                     "name": "Test Folder 2",
                     "source": "unknown",
                     "type": "folder"
                  }, {
                     "date_added": "13291325578774403",
                     "date_last_used": "13311405413618157",
                     "guid": "c9224ca2-4434-4a01-8458-7737bd4b1c83",
                     "id": "12",
                     "name": "Capital One | AutoPay ✅ Account Summary",
                     "show_icon": false,
                     "source": "unknown",
                     "type": "url",
                     "url": "https://myaccounts.capitalone.com/accountSummary"
                  }, {
                     "date_added": "13291325692105642",
                     "date_last_used": "0",
                     "guid": "27454c4e-31db-4cda-9e95-eb3c27c26d15",
                     "id": "13",
                     "name": "Citibank Online | AutoPay ✅",
                     "show_icon": false,
                     "source": "unknown",
                     "type": "url",
                     "url": "https://online.citi.com/US/ag/dashboard/credit-card"
                  } ],
                  "date_added": "13312413876662602",
                  "date_last_used": "0",
                  "date_modified": "13312413896191672",
                  "guid": "a4f4d3e8-4f43-438e-8ab6-6ee4c3573e9e",
                  "id": "22",
                  "name": "Test Folder",
                  "source": "unknown",
                  "type": "folder"
               } ],
               "date_added": "13264531539040210",
               "date_last_used": "0",
               "date_modified": "13312413888903618",
               "guid": "b3c11fcd-bd4d-43c3-ba6e-9eff5831a6a3",
               "id": "8",
               "name": "Credit Cards",
               "source": "unknown",
               "type": "folder"
            } ],
            "date_added": "13261848398917139",
            "date_last_used": "0",
            "date_modified": "13296202141696211",
            "guid": "2774132c-4326-4a40-9dd9-ed8296551977",
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Banking",
            "source": "unknown",
            "type": "folder"
         } ],
         "date_added": "13312350037425721",
         "date_last_used": "0",
         "date_modified": "13312350129825542",
         "guid": "0bc5d13f-2cba-5d74-951f-3f233fe6c908",
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Favorites bar",
         "source": "unknown",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "other": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13312350037425723",
         "date_last_used": "0",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "82b081ec-3dd3-529c-8475-ab6c344590dd",
         "id": "19",
         "name": "Other favorites",
         "source": "unknown",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "synced": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13312350037425725",
         "date_last_used": "0",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "4cf2e351-0e85-532b-bb37-df045d8f8d0f",
         "id": "20",
         "name": "Mobile favorites",
         "source": "unknown",
         "type": "folder"
      }
   },
   "version": 1
}
```

Sample `parent_folder` output:

```json
{
         "children": [ {
            "children": [ {
               "children": [ {
                  "children": [ {
                     "children": [ {
                        "date_added": "13264531526257514",
                        "date_last_used": "13312079908225289",
                        "guid": "28a9a0b5-9358-435c-a961-183877d528c5",
                        "id": "9",
                        "name": "Log In to My Account | American Express US",
                        "show_icon": false,
                        "source": "unknown",
                        "type": "url",
                        "url": "https://www.americanexpress.com/en-us/account/login"
                     }, {
                        "date_added": "13264624495902630",
                        "date_last_used": "13311480110897463",
                        "guid": "eb271305-3da6-47b0-9b29-0b188a49de4c",
                        "id": "10",
                        "name": "Discover Card: Session Ended",
                        "show_icon": false,
                        "source": "unknown",
                        "type": "url",
                        "url": "https://portal.discover.com/customersvcs/universalLogin/timeout_confirmed"
                     } ],
                     "date_added": "13312413888903462",
                     "date_last_used": "0",
                     "date_modified": "13312413894732480",
                     "guid": "45822356-c1a0-4644-a36b-d1805994bff1",
                     "id": "23",
                     "name": "Test Folder 2",
                     "source": "unknown",
                     "type": "folder"
                  }, {
                     "date_added": "13291325578774403",
                     "date_last_used": "13311405413618157",
                     "guid": "c9224ca2-4434-4a01-8458-7737bd4b1c83",
                     "id": "12",
                     "name": "Capital One | AutoPay ✅ Account Summary",
                     "show_icon": false,
                     "source": "unknown",
                     "type": "url",
                     "url": "https://myaccounts.capitalone.com/accountSummary"
                  }, {
                     "date_added": "13291325692105642",
                     "date_last_used": "0",
                     "guid": "27454c4e-31db-4cda-9e95-eb3c27c26d15",
                     "id": "13",
                     "name": "Citibank Online | AutoPay ✅",
                     "show_icon": false,
                     "source": "unknown",
                     "type": "url",
                     "url": "https://online.citi.com/US/ag/dashboard/credit-card"
                  } ],
                  "date_added": "13312413876662602",
                  "date_last_used": "0",
                  "date_modified": "13312413896191672",
                  "guid": "a4f4d3e8-4f43-438e-8ab6-6ee4c3573e9e",
                  "id": "22",
                  "name": "Test Folder",
                  "source": "unknown",
                  "type": "folder"
               } ],
               "date_added": "13264531539040210",
               "date_last_used": "0",
               "date_modified": "13312413888903618",
               "guid": "b3c11fcd-bd4d-43c3-ba6e-9eff5831a6a3",
               "id": "8",
               "name": "Credit Cards",
               "source": "unknown",
               "type": "folder"
            } ],
            "date_added": "13261848398917139",
            "date_last_used": "0",
            "date_modified": "13296202141696211",
            "guid": "2774132c-4326-4a40-9dd9-ed8296551977",
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Banking",
            "source": "unknown",
            "type": "folder"}
```

Comment: Maybe you can edit the question, put there sample input dictionary and what output you want to get...

Comment: You need a recursive function to process hierarchical data with arbitrary depth.

Comment: @jangles According the edit, maybe `dct['roots']['bookmark_bar']` will get the result?

Comment: @Barmar that makes sense! I'll work on that.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I'm looking to get a specific folder that could be a subdirectory, if I just got the root of the bookmark bar I would be retrieving all of the bookmark folders, including the ones that I might not want.

Comment: You can do it without recursion, but you'll need to maintain your own stack to keep track of which branch you are digging down into. Recursion is easier and, assuming you don't have very large and very lopsided tree, safe.

Comment: @chepner Thinking recursively is very difficult for me, so I will consider this too. Thank you!